# How to update jQuery Cycle pager after finish of animation?

Tags: slider, jquery-cycle, pager

I'm using the jQuery Cycle plugin and I would like to change updating of pager.
Is it possible to update pager not after click but after change of slide?

Answer (score 0):

There is an event you can change to update the active pager element.

See documentation from plugin site:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager7.html

Working JsFiddle Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/KWUqj/2/